# Connecting/Adding a private network on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a dual server configuration on a host provider using VPS. I was told by my Host provider that in order to use free bandwidth between my two servers (they are in the same location) I need to add a alias "subnet" to a specific ip (A private network, VPN).

How do I add an aliased ip in widnwos? 
in Linux the relevant command is supposed to be (By my search in blogs) 
"ifconfig eth0:1 10.129.175.165 netmask 255.255.255.0"

They also said that another way to connect between the servers (should also be faster) is to use "private lan", but as it happens I don't know how to define one :(.

Is there a windows equivalent or another way to do this?

I have checked my ip config and found no indication of the private lan or the VPN ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a private network between the two servers only if they have additional NICs that are connected to each other (directly or via a Switch etc). You can do all of this through the Network Connections GUI but if you want to do it from the command line you can get it all done via the Netsh command. Be sure to start this from an elevated command prompt if you are on Windows 2008.

```
netsh interface show interface
```

That will list all available adapters. If you have more than one physical (wired) NIC they will show up as LAN Connection 1, 2 etc.

```
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection 1
```

This shows a system with two LAN adapters that are detecting that they are connected to something. If you don't have a second adapter you can't set up a completely private network between your servers and if the second adapter is listed as disconnected you will probably need to get someone to resolve that by visiting the servers to plug in some cables.

You can list the current address and other configuration data for the interfaces with the show config command so you can be certain which interfaces are available for you to use, and in which way.

```
netsh interface ipv4 show config
```

Mind you `ipconfig /all` will give you pretty much the same info (and covers ipv6 at the same time).

You can set the ipv4 address on an unconfigured interface as follows.

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address "Local Area Connection 1" static 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 1
```

The parameters after "static" are ip-address, netmask, gateway and gateway metric. Be careful that you are not selecting the primary interface of your server with that as you will almost certainly lose connectivity if you execute that on a remote system with your primary interface selected.

You can also add additional ipv4 addresses to an existing NIC provided it is not already configured for DHCP. This option is almost certain to work for you as it is what your provider described as adding an "aliased ip".

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address "Local Area Connection 1" static 192.168.2.10 255.255.255.0
```

Given that you will already have a default gateway you can leave out the gateway options.

Comment: One suggestion - up top, you say this is only possible if you have extra NICs. Near the bottom, you describe how to add additional IPs to existing NICs, which would definitely be something that he could do; might want to clarify.

Comment: True enough, I thought I was being clear but possibly wasn't. The first option is for setting the ipv4 address on an interface, it will wipe out any pre-existing address if used on an interface that's already configured with an address which is why it shouldn't be used on a system with only one NIC. The second option adds an extra address without removing any addresses that are already configured - which is why it can be used for what he wants to do (if he only has one NIC).

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortionatly I cannot test this solutions for my servers for a while. I will do so and report back here.